# Best practices: use `np.dot(A,B)` or `A.dot(B)`, and why?

Tags: python, numpy

`A` and `B` being matrices (arrays), is there any reason to use `np.dot(A,B)` or `A.dot(B)` beyond personal preference and readability (which imho is a bit personal for this case)?

Is one possibly faster or something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that there are not relevant performance differences. But if you are to use some advanced libraries working on top of numpy, it might be wise to use the former. Example from [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd): ```Similarly, we don't support the syntax A.dot(B); use the equivalent np.dot(A, B) instead. The reason we don't support the first way is that subclassing ndarray raises a host of issues. As another consequence of not subclassing ndarray, some subclass checks can break, like isinstance(x, np.ndarray) can return False.```

Comment: The docs make no indication of this, neither did the [release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/doc/release/1.5.0-notes.rst#dot-method-for-ndarrays) for when `.dot` was added as a method. The only difference is look-ups from Pythons side, for `np.dot` is has to do a bit more; the time difference though is absolutely minuscule due to how much `dot` takes in comparison.

Comment: Thanks guys. Indeed my gut feeling was to go with np.dot(A,B) as it seems more straightforward and readable to me, but many places seemed to implicitly suggest the method was better, and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Actually both a `built-in`.  There are other functions that use Python code to delegate the action to the best method (e.g. `np.sum`).  But in the `np.dot` case this is done in compiled code.  You can look that up on the numpy github.

Comment: Maybe... with the second form you have to know, in advance, the *name* of at least one of the arrays - while with the first form, you can feed it ndarrays without knowing their names, in fact they don't even have to be *named* - it allows you to be a bit more abstract if that is needed.

Comment: It looks like the `np.dot` form came first, and the `A.dot` form was added to facilitate chaining (`A.dot(B).dot(C)`).  New versions have a `@` operator that can be used instead.